# Look back further than one record lag

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I've got a table which tracks items in locations. Since this table is fed by two separate systems, the dates can overlap.  Lets call them System1 and System2.

I'm using partitions to examine when dates are overlapping, but hit a snag when the record with an error is not an adjacent row.  i.e. the first record from System2 exists within a record from System1, so is discarded, however the second record in System2 either starts before the end of the last record in System2 or is likewise within the last record.

To solve this I am attempting to capture the last end date in System1, so I can easily check my dates against this value.  My issue is I don't know enough about partitions to do this.  I essentially need a partition over a partition.  The main partition is based on a PartID, and the second is based on SysID or you could even use the Source I guess.  To make things neat I renamed the unique record id to just a single digit ID in the sample data below.

Current code is just a series of LEAD/LAG statements partitions over PartID   ordered by ADTM

Sample data:
For this data, I'm currently correctly identifying the records with single * as errors.  The one with ** however is an unidentified error since it is encompassed by record 3757871 from System1.  I need to be able to compare the dates of ID 6 to that of ID 4 so I can identify that fault.

```
Source        SysID     PartID   ID       ADTM                SDTM
System1     A8871247    1661181  1   2014-08-15 11:21   2014-08-15 11:35
*System2    1661181     1661181  2   2014-08-15 11:27   2014-08-19 11:04*
System1     A8871247    1661181  3   2014-08-15 11:35   2014-08-16 22:43
System1     A8871247    1661181  4   2014-08-16 22:43   2014-08-20 15:44
*System2    1661181     1661181  5   2014-08-19 11:04   2014-08-19 11:05*
**System2   1661181     1661181  6   2014-08-19 11:05   2014-08-20 15:30**
System2     1661181     1661181  7   2014-08-20 15:30   2014-08-20 15:44
System2     1661181     1661181  8   2014-08-20 15:44   2014-08-22 11:34
```

My end result is ID 2,5,6, and 7 will be discarded, and ID 8 will have it's ADTM updated to be the SDTM of ID 4 to create a seamless transition between systems.

Basically what I need is the `MAX(SDTM) OVER(PARTITION BY PartID ORDER BY ADTM WHERE Source = 'System1')`

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the complete goal, why is ID 7 not an error?  -It's times are within ID 4's times.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  That's an error too.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have another question: if you have a partial overlap (suppose ID 9 had ADTM = 2014-08-22 11:30 and SDTM = 2014-08-23 11:50) would that be considered an error or would you update the SDTM to be the max ADTM of the previous non-error (as per the example, 2014-08-22 11:34).

Comment: Nope that would be fine.  A process further along would update the ADTM of ID 9 and make it 11:34.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I definitely do not know exactly what you are trying to do, but based on your actual question, you can get the max SDTM over all previous rows using something like this:

```
with t2 as (
    select *, max(SDTM) over (partition by PartID order by ADTM, ID) maxSDTM
    from table_name
)
select *, lag(maxSDTM, 1) over (partition by PartID order by ADTM, ID)
from t2
```

By using an over clause with MAX, you are making it a window function and getting the highest SDTM of all previous rows including the current row.  Then you need to basically exclude the current row so you can use LAG to get the previous max.  Hope this helps, sorry I didn't understand your end goal.

Old: I may not be understanding the problem, but if so my instinct would be instead to use a self-join.  The following query should identify all errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t
JOIN table_name prev
ON (t.ADTM > prev.ADTM OR (t.ADTM = prev.ADTM AND t.ID > prev.ID))
    AND t.SDTM <= prev.SDTM
    AND t.PartID = prev.PartID
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.   What i'm really after is just a way to capture the max sdtm of system1 in the partition over PartID

Comment: You want the max SDTM per Part ID?  That would be a group by operation.  Or do you want the max SDTM per row partitioned by Part ID and prior to the current row?